# Should I use a database with back4app

Tags: android, back4app

I am building a Q&A app for android and I am using Back4App.

Is there a way to achieve the following without creating a local data:

- Get random question.
- Keep data when user offline.
- Update data when the user is online.

Answer (score 0):

Back4App is a BaaS, there you can save information regarding a user to the Database, using the Android SDK, you can save your objects offline ([check here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#saving-objects-offline)) and The Local Datastore doesn’t need to be saved to the cloud, you can check more [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#the-local-datastore).

You can work with a separate logic using in your Cloud Code section, there, you can deploy your code if you need to implement a different logic, read more [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions).

Also, it seems that you need to manage your objects on the cloud, at the moment, you can read the guides below:

- [Create Object](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#saving-objects)
- [Retrieve Object](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#retrieving-objects)
- [Update Object](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#updating-objects)
- [Delete Object](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#deleting-objects)

Comment: how I can get a random question from my database to show it to the user?

Comment: Hi! It is necessary to implement your Logic to get the random questions from your class, for example, you can use Cloud Code to call this function in your app, you can read more about it:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions

And also, you can retrieve objects using the JS SDK like: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#basic-queries

Comment: So I should use a cloud function or a local database right?